# How to pass the text pasted in a textbox to javascript function using onPaste event?

Tags: javascript, html, input, paste

I have an HTML page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onPaste="return myfunction()"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a javascript like this:

```
function myfunction(){
    var text = ;
    if(text == "ABC"){
        alert("Accepted");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("Rejected");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to assign the pasted `String` to the `var text`

This question may seem like a duplicate. But, I want to acheive this without `jquery`.

Comment: Check out the [documentation at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.onpaste) which contains an example.

Comment: and a red box with "Non-standard
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

Comment: `if (text = "ABC")` is always true (you assign "ABC" to your variable and "ABC" is true in boolean context). You want `if (text == "ABC")`.

Comment: @basic6 That was by mistake..

Comment: @JeremyMiller I read that. It was a bit confusing for me. Thats why I have posted here.

Comment: @mplungjan I read that too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lqdfa9co/

I added this:

```
onPaste="var e=this; setTimeout(function(){myfunction(e)}, 4);"
```

and the function was changed to this:

```
function myfunction(e){
    var text = e.value;
    if(text === "ABC"){
        alert("Accepted");
    }
    else{
        alert("Rejected");
    }
}
```

It is necessary to use a `setTimeout` on `onPaste` event in order to get the value inside the function. This is caused by the fact that the event is triggered before the value is assigned

**Edit**: In order to answer to the changed question, I updated the "Rejected phase" emptying the input value http://jsfiddle.net/Lqdfa9co/1/

Comment: This works.. But now I have edited my question.. Can you check on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getElementById` function to do something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="myTextBox" type="text" onChange="myFunction()"></input>
  </body>
</html>

function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: `onChange="myfunction(this)"` and `function myFunction(txtBox){var text = txtBox.value: }`

Comment: This does not work. myfunction() will be called before the text is pasted. So, document.getElementById('myTextBox').value does not retrieve any value..

Comment: Seems to work for me. Atleast when you unfocus the control. See http://jsfiddle.net/oanwhmwp/

Comment: I have edited my question now. Can you check on that?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<input onkeyup="isNumberKey(this);">

function isNumberKey(mmcs)
{ 
 mmcs.value = mmcs.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,""); //sólo números
 //mmcs.value = mmcs.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""); //números y puntos
}
```